# How can I filter views within views and override all output including grouped fields?

Tags: 8, views

**EDIT:**
User error. I was doing it wrong. You CAN customize the output of grouped "hidden" fields. Even though they are hidden from being repeated, whatever settings you have for them will work for the grouped version.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I have TWO content types: "Business" and "Business Offers/Events" that I'd like to combine for a view. I want to group all Business Offers by their respective businesses. But I also want to user to be able to filter the offers by the day of the week (Mon - Sunday). Most of the "offers" are repeating events like happy hours. I use the [date_recur](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_recur) field to store the repeating event rule (or RRule). The date_recur field doesn't hold specific day of the week values anywhere, so in order to properly filter offers this way, I have to use a grouped filter (with 7 filters for each day of the week, each with a slightly different regex expression for each day).

Here's a sample of the raw input of the rrule subfield:

```
FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;INTERVAL=1
```

And here's a regex example of a filter (for Monday):

```
([A-Z=;0-9])*(BYDAY=)([A-Z]{2},)*(MO)(,|;|$)+([A-Z]{2}(,|;|$))*([A-Z=;0-9])*
```

I'd like my view listings to look like this (before the offers are filtered):

```
BUSINESS NAME
(other business details/photos etc)
OFFERS:
 - Taco Tuesdays (Title of Offer #1)
   (offer details etc)
   [raw rrule: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=TU;INTERVAL=1]
 - Happy Hours (Title of Offer #2)
   (offer details etc)
   [raw rrule: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;INTERVAL=1]
 - Brunch (Title of Offer #3)
   (offer details etc)
   [raw rrule: FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU;INTERVAL=1]
 - etc
```

I have tried several things:

1. I created an Offers view, with a relationship to the Business, then grouped the fields by the business fields. I then hid the repetitious grouped business fields..added the Offers fields...and created the necessary filters (which worked). BUT...then I realized that I couldn't customize the output of the grouped fields like I could with the offers fields (I have some pretty hardcore css/javascript for this section for a custom slideshow, z-index layers, etc) so I can't just try targeting the elements with external css (or maybe I don't want to unless I have to).
2. I then tried to create two views so I didn't have to use grouped fields, and employed the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module in the Business view to pass a contextual filter (the business nid) to the embedded field view (of the Offers). I was able to successfully show X amount of offers under each business...and could now customize the output of all fields (albeit in two different views), BUT this now didn't allow me to ALSO filter the offers by the day of the week (or indeed filter out businesses altogether if they had no offers for a particular day). I tried passing additional contextual filters even as a proof of concept, but was unable to pass a "regex" expression to the matching field via this views_field_view module.

I do have several other ideas for attacking this problem...but I can't help but wonder if I'm spinning my wheels and just don't know drupal well enough anymore to think of a more straightforward solution.

Do any of you drupal/views pros know of a better way of configuring things so I can have FULL control over all output of all fields grouped or ungrouped AND be able to filter out offers and/or businesses by day of the week?

Comment: You _can_ style grouped fields, you can Rewrite output and adjust the Style settings, just like any other field, even when the grouped field is set to `Exclude from display`. Can you explain what is actually stopping your from styling the grouped fields? I wouldn't use your second solution unless it's absolutely necessary, because of performance.

Comment: You're right. I'm an idiot. For some reason I thought because by hiding the output of the repeating fields, that it was only rendering the default styles. I think I thought it didn't work because I tried adding a style tag to one of the elements...and I've just learned that "style" gets stripped out...but "class" does not. Thank you for setting me straight.